# Formatting of 2D arrays of chars

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, formatting, char

I have a program which reads in a pair of integers from a file and stores that in a Point class which i have created. The first integer is the x coordinate and the second is the y coordinate on each line of the file. All valid points have **x-coordinates in the range [0, 40]** and **y-coordinates in the range [1, 20]**.

> The input file contains data like this:

[image]

*I performed some validation checks so that my program ignores invalid data or out of range data.*

I then have to plot a regression line on top of those points. **I have to use 2D arrays of chars and would prefer to do it this way insetad of using Point2D class of java or some other graphical classes of java.**

*"X"s is used to represent the points, "-"s the regression line segments, and "*"s where a line segment and a point are located at the same spot*

Th formula used for regression line is this:

[image]

**# Edit #**

Below is the code snippet that i got from @sprinter:

```
initializeArray(charArray);
  int xySum = 0;
  int xSqSum = 0;
  int xSum = 0;
  int ySum = 0;
  for (Point points: point) {
    xySum += points.getX() * points.getY();
    xSqSum += points.getX() * points.getX();
    xSum += points.getX();
    ySum += points.getY();
  }
  int xMean = xSum / count;
  int yMean = ySum / count;
  int n = point.size();
  int slope = (xySum - n* xMean * yMean) / (xSqSum - n * xMean * xMean);

    for (Point points: point) {
      charArray[points.getX()][points.getY()] = 'X';
    }
     // plot the regression line
    for (int x = 0; x <charArray.length; x++) {
      int y = yMean + slope * (x - xMean); // calculate regression value
        charArray[x][y] = charArray[x][y] == 'X' ? '*' : '-';
    }
```

**This is my program's output after i ran *sprinter's* code.:**

[image]

**whereas i want output like this:**
[image]

Also this is how i am initializing the charArray:

```
public static void initializeArray(char[][] charArray) {
  for(int k =0; k< charArray.length; k++) {
      for(int d = 0; d<charArray[k].length;d++) {
        charArray[k][d] = ' ';
      }
    }
}
```

**This is the new output:**

[image]

Comment: It is a big question to read but the description is small, the pics took a lot of space. Again i am happy to provide more info.

Comment: have you printed out what you get for the slope and yPred?

Comment: Yes i do values for the slope as well as the yPred value. @RAZ_Muh_Taz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding it hard to understand what the `fillArray` function is supposed to do. You could have multiple 'y' values for each 'x' value in your list of points so i assume you are calling this once for each point. But the regression line has lots of 'x' values that aren't in the list of points which means you would have to call this once for each regression point. You also don't need to return the array after filling the value.

Your slope calculation doesn't seem to match the formula at all. This would make more sense to me:

```
float xySum = 0;
float xSqSum = 0;
float xSum = 0;
float ySum = 0;
for (Point point: points) {
    xySum += point.x * point.y;
    xSqSum += point.x * point.x;
    xSum += point.x;
    ySum += point.y;
}
float xMean = xSum / count;
float yMean = ySum / count;
float n = points.size();
float slope = (xySum - n* xMean * yMean) / (xSqSum - n * xMean * xMean);
```

I suspect you would be much better off plotting all the points then plotting the regression line.

```
List<Point> points = ...;
// first plot the points
for (Point point: points) {
    array[point.x][point.y] = 'X';
}
// now plot the regression line
for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
    int y = Math.round(yMean + slope * (x - xMean));
    array[x][y] = array[x][y] == 'X' ? '*' : '-';
}
```

By the way, if you are familiar with Java 8 streams then you could use:

```
double n = points.size();
double xySum = points.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.x * p.y).sum();
double xSqSum = points.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.x * p.x).sum();
double xMean = points.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.x).sum() / n;
double yMean = points.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.y).sum() / n;
```

Finally, your x dimension is the first and y dimension second. So to print you need to iterate through y first, not x:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
        System.out.print(array[x][20-y-1]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: But i have to plot the regression line on top of the points, will it be possible with your method?

Comment: I just copied your code into my program but there is still some issue with the output. If you want me to put the pic, just let me know.  The "-" character are still like the first pic, which is posted above. They are stacked on top of each other at the same spot. Also there are no "*" displayed in the output. @sprinter

Comment: I just updated the question and i have also added the output from the code that you provided me. i have also posted the initializeArray method as well which i think could be the source of the problem as i have initialized the array with '  ' space characters after suggestion from friends. It was not posted here before even though it was in my program from the beginning. Sorry i had to remove my other output as the question was getting messier. I hope you will be able to help me. @sprinter

Comment: Your printing looks like it's swapping x and y. The reason the regression line is flat is rounding to ints. I'll change to floats.

Comment: I just changed int to float and now it is giving me precision error on this line `            `charArray[x][y] = charArray[x][y] == 'X' ? '*' : '-';`

Comment: the y variable needs to remain an int. See my code in the answer.

Comment: I don't believe it is due to the float or int. The '-' char is printing vertically on the same column which is a problem. Also it should print asterisk but it is printing '-' and 'X' char only. This is just my opinion and understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127075/discussion-between-sprinter-and-saad).